# Import packages from outside django project

Tags: python, django

Context: The package being considered is an application that was developed by another team and I want to use the functionality exposed as part of an API call in my django project.

Directory layout:

```
<repo>
├── org_wide_django_code
│   ├── my_django_project
│   │   ├── my_django_project
│   │   ├── manage.py
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   └── my_application
├── frontend
│   └── application
├── other_team_work
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── implemented_logic
```

What is the best way for me to use `other_team_work` in my django project `my_django_project`?

Prior reading:

- Manipulating `PYTHONPATH` or sys.path is an option
- Setting up a `.whl` or `.egg` to install `other_team_work` (also need to add a `setup.py` there)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Read this, for start https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _ Read about it in your favorite programming book_; it was in reference to that. I was asking for your recommendation on the book to read given how insightful that comment was.

Comment: Asking me such questions is a privilege, not a right

Comment: Have you already read the answer in your favorite book?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a best way since this depends a lot on the internal tooling of your organisation. However the main thing to pay attention to IMO are release and development cycles. Ideally you want both teams to be able to release new features, functionalities without impacting the other. (for instance if `other_team` makes a change to their code for a third team you would like this to have no possible impact on your application. Similarly `other_team` should not need to know how and when you use their module to make changes to their application.

One way to do this would be to have `other_team_work` be packaged and installable (using a `setup.py`) and then pushed to a package registery (for instance [gitlab's package registery](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/) or [github packages](https://github.com/features/packages)). This way you can use `other_team_work` as though it were just another python package with `pip` (using the [extra-package-url](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-extra-index-url) argument) and using specific versions in a `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (but can be dangerous) is add `other_team_work` to your project in PYTHONPATH. You can add this to django `settings.py` file, after `BASE_DIR` definition.
Example:

```
import sys

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent  # default Django base dir
OTHER_TEAM_WORK_PARENT_DIR = BASE_DIR.parent  # in accordance with your directories
sys.path.append(str(OTHER_TEAM_WORK_PARENT_DIR))
```

This code add your directory `org_wide_django_code` to PYTHONPATH and you can import `other_team_work` in your code:

```
from other_team_work import implemented_logic
```